# Extract namespace into separate CHM file

Tags: c#, documentation, documentation-generation, chm

I have a namespace with several C# classes that I want to review with my distributed team. I am facing the issue of sharing the big CHM file with my peers (Can't use public sharing sites) so I thought of only sharing the namespace under review.

Is there a way to extract a namespace documentation (preferably CHM format) from the parent CHM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. You could write a program for it

1. extract the CHM
2. selecting the relevant html files, and identifying helper files (like .css)
3. deleting the rest,
4. fixing up the links to files you deleted(3) in files you keep(2)
5. fixing up the index and TOC, pray they are not binary.
6. repack the whole thing.

The selection and fixing up part is probably dependent on the generator tool (and version) used to craft the original CHM.

Anyway, in theory it is possible, but I think there will be nothing read made.